# с++: проверка вхождения битовой последовательности в соответствующую маску с использованием bit manipulation instructions set

Tags: c++, c, битовые-операции

есть некоторая битовая последовательность, записанная в числе

```
data = 0b01101000
```

надо определить, что она полностью покрывается битовой последовательностью (маской), записанной в другом числе

```
mask = 0b01101011
```

для этого можно использовать два идентичных алгоритма:

```
mask | data == mask
```

и

```
~mask & data == 0
```

Подскажите, а есть ли какая-нибудь инструкция (или совокупность инструкций) процессоров x86, x64, которая делает тоже самое (смотрю инструкции операций с битами, но не совсем въезжаю)

Оптимально конечно было бы, если бы существовала некоторая функция/инструкция, которая выдавала бы `1`, если последовательность полностью покрывается маской и `0` в противном случае

вроде как есть инструкция `ANDN` (`~x & y`), но в той же visual studio она доступна только для mmx регистров (`_m_pandn`), что несколько избыточно и опять же все равно результат надо будет сравнивать

Comment: Чем это отличается от банального сравнения последовательности и маски?

Comment: @gbg, скоростью, например для `проверить n-ый бит, выдать его и сбросить` есть отдельная команда и не надо делать несколько логических операций, вот и подумалось - маскирование тоже довольно часто используемая операция и может для нее тоже есть отдельная команда

Comment: Если дело только в скорости, нужно понимание того, что вы будете делать с результатом данного сравнения.
Если вам нужно его просто куда-то сохранить, используйте XOR. 
Если вам нужно сделать ветвление - у вас есть сравнение.

Comment: №1. Скорость логических операций  не уступит скорости любой другой операции,  №2.  Не  знал, что одну  конкретную операцию стоит назвать алгоритмом....

Comment: @gbg,  мне надо подсчитать сколько в буфере из N байт таких ситуаций, сейчас мне приходится делать `if (...) count ++`, если придумать короткий алгоритм, который выдает `0` или `1`, то тогда можно делать `count += func(...)` что значительно ускорит данный алгоритм ибо не будет `if`, который очень не любят процессоры, у меня был способ как получить `0/1`, но он требовал значительного числа битовых операций, что сводило ускорение к нулю и даже замедляло относительно `if`, поэтому если бы была соответствующая инструкция, то все было бы поприятнее

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, конечно не уступает - 1 тик он и в Африке 1 тик, а вот 3 логические операции уже будут уступать одной специализированной :) Касательно же операция/алгоритм - ну это как подсчет установленных бит в `int` - если через `for` + `&` + '<<' делать - это алгоритм, а если через `__popcnt`, то можно алгоритмом и не называть :)

Comment: Ну, используйте https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-ISA-Extensions/Optimizing-XOR-and-Popcount-using-AVX2/td-p/1176890

Comment: Посмотрите простую ассемблерную компиляцию https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ExjWKv  Будет очень быстро пахать, вплоть до 64 бит. Вопрос : Какого размера должны быть числа? Намёк : не забывайте про скобки.